# How to retrieve Attachment's FileName with CSOM

Tags: csom, splistitem

I need to check if attachment already exists:

```
ListItem item = list.GetItemById(_id);
context.Load(item, l => l.AttachmentFiles);
context.ExecuteQuery();

if (item.AttachmentFiles.Any(x => x.FileName == _filename))
    // do something
```

This gives me error

> The property or field 'FileName' has not been initialized.

How can I initialize `FileName` property of attachments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `GetByFileName` method of the `AttachmentFiles` to determine whether the attachment exists or not.

Modify your code as below:

```
ListItem item = list.GetItemById(_id);
context.Load(item, l => l.AttachmentFiles);
context.ExecuteQuery();

try
{
    var attachment = item.AttachmentFiles.GetByFileName(_filename);
    context.Load(attachment);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    // file doesn't exist
    // do something
}
```

Reference - [AttachmentCollection.GetByFileName method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.attachmentcollection.getbyfilename.aspx)

You can also make use of the `GetFileByServerRelativeUrl` to determine whether file exists or not as below:

```
string relativeUrl = $"/sites/test/Lists/Custom List/Attachments/{_id}/{_filename}";

try
{
    var file = context.Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl(relativeUrl);
    context.Load(file);
    context.ExecuteQuery();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    //do something if file not found
}
```

Reference - [Web.GetFileByServerRelativeUrl method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.web.getfilebyserverrelativeurl.aspx)